# Why is "access denied" to multisheet charts in published Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I can successfully include a chart based on a single sheet, but as soon as I combine ranges from multiple sheets, I get an access denied error.

[Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsofkDcAtXiwdGpPZzhWZDY2aURSbmo3STUyeVRfWUE#gid=2)
[Published spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AsofkDcAtXiwdGpPZzhWZDY2aURSbmo3STUyeVRfWUE&gid=2)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: currently only 18 views. cross posted to http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/drive/s20Z9o6NMPA/discussion

Comment: 36 views as of 2012-10-25

Comment: 100 views! 0 answers :(

Comment: I guess you're not doing anything wrong. In your file, I added the sheet range of sheet 1, via the ARRAYFORMULA, changed the chart, published and was able to see the chart. Apparently, it's not possible, +1 for waiting !!

Comment: 190 views! 0 answers :(

Comment: One reaction on the 15th of Febr. No response.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late, but I figure this will be useful for future searchers.

The answer seems to be that you need to create an intermediate sheet with both sets of values. The intermediate sheet ("combined data") has two cells with formulas:

```
A1 =ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!A:C)
D1 =ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet2!A:C)
```

The chart uses the following as its data:

```
'combined data'!D1:E14, 'combined data'!B1:B8
```

I have created a spreadsheet for you to look at:

[Multisheet chart spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Au17ekRhm0HjdGFGUVVHTm9CTlJJOF8tZWhZcVB2emc&usp=sharing)

and [a published chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Au17ekRhm0HjdGFGUVVHTm9CTlJJOF8tZWhZcVB2emc&single=true&gid=6&output=html)

ps - just as it hits 300 views!